Literature on Bochner spaces on general measure spaces
Considering Bochner-measurable functions $u: T \rightarrow X$ from a general measure space $(T,\Sigma, \mu)$ to a Banach space $(X, ||\cdot ||_X)$ gives raise to Bochner spaces. However, the books I found on this topic restrict themselves to the case where $T= I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is some interval (usually in the context of parabolic PDEs).
Are there any textbooks, papers or lecture notes for the general case? Maybe some standard reference that everyone working in this fields should know?

Lang’s real analysis, Amann Escher Volume III (they restrict themselves to complete $\sigma$-finite spaces, but it’s not necessary for a lot of the basics). Also, Hytonen (and others) have a book called Analysis on Banach Spaces, Volume I: Martingales and Paley-Littlewood Theory (just chapter 1, and perhaps 2 should be enough).

Vector Measures by Diestel and Uhl.

Thanks to both of you!
